# creating a custom object .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I know we can call a user control with parameters like this:

```
<myLib:myObject runat="server" param1="<%= getParam1() %>" param2="<%= getParam2() %>"></myLib:myObject>
```

I need to pass more complex information to object, something like this:

```
<myLib:myObject runat="server">
  <param1 param1Feature1="feature1.1" param1Feature2="feature1.2" />

  <param2 param1Feature1="feature2.1">
    <feature2 value="feature2.2"/>
  </DeleteCommand>

  <param3>
        <h2>Some HTML content</h2>
        <p>some html content</p>
  </param3>
</myLib:myObject>
```

A famous commercial component uses this method to pass more than a simple ID to the component. I hoping to use same functionality in a project but I just dont know which object or method to use to achieve this.

Thanks for your time/help.